# "Тысяча" - что это?

Tags: части-речи

Тысяча - это числительное или существительное?

Answer (score 2):

Если кратко, слово *тысяча* — существительное. Это явствует из того, что оно во всех падежах **управляет** существительными, называющими считаемые предметы: *тысяча человек, тысячи человек, тысячу рублей, о тысяче человек* и др. Грамматические признаки числительного оно обнаруживает лишь в форме твор. п. *тысячью* (существующей наряду с формой твор. п. существительного *тысячей*): **согласовывается** в падеже с зависящим от него существительным *(с тысячью рублями).*

Comment: Спасибо за ваши полные и понятные ответы. Всегда приятно узнавать что-то новое, даже если сам при этом ошибался))

Comment: И еще вопрос в  тему: один это числительное, но изменяется как прилагательное, а в контексте может выступать в роли даже местоимения. Может, и с тысячей та же ситуация?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что нужно смотреть на то, что она означает в конкретном случае. Если это неопределенное число, то - имя существительное. Определенное же число однозначно должно быть числительным.

Comment: Разве в ответе Парис де Ниша не об этом же сказано? И потом: «нужно смотреть на то, что она означает»... Она — число или существительное?

Answer (score 0):

Это слово - числительное, но может субстантивироваться (переходить в существительное).
Форма тысяЧЬЮ - специфическая форма числительного, тысяЧЕЙ - форма существительного.